# non negative distributional derivative

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $J$ be an open interval and let $f:J\to\mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable. Suppose that for all $0\leq\theta\in C^\infty_c(J)$ it holds
$$  
\int_J f(t)\,\theta'(t)\,dt\geq 0\,,
$$
namely the first distributional derivative of $f$ is non-negative.

Can one conclude that $f$ is non-increasing? Or does one need further assumptions?

The idea is the following: the equation tells us that actually $f'$ is not just a distribution but even a positive measure on $J$. How can I go on from this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: At least $f$ can be increasing on null sets.

Comment: For example, consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x & \text{ if }x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},\\
x & \text{ if }x \in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}$$
Its distributional derivative is negative, but $f$ is not decreasing.